# Helmet with flip-down binoculars is not in any of the databases

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands, accessories

[image: Helmet with flip down binoculars][image]

The helmet has 10198 inside but I cannot find that on any of the usual part databases. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a 3rd-party LEGO-compatible accessory, several 3rd-parties make such military themed accessories.

LEGO doesn't make very many modern-day military-themed pieces and I found similar pieces on [one 3rd-party accessory shop](http://minifigworld.com/ach-helmet/). It's not an exact match, but it's pretty close. It might be that you have an older version of their product, or some competitor's product.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I was just beginning to suspect it isn’t actually Lego even though the type face of the number looks correct. I appreciate your reply, thanks.